Class D audio amplifier: Choosing the appropriate MOSFETs and Gate drivers
I’m a university student working on a project to design and build a 50W Class D audio amplifier, and I’m still learning the ropes regarding electronics. I’m facing some challenges with selecting the right gate driver and MOSFETs for my circuit, and I’d appreciate your guidance.

What I’ve Built So Far
I’ve successfully designed a PWM module based on some online references. The circuit generates a PWM signal at 300kHz (carrier frequency) with an input signal frequency of 20kHz.

PWM Output Range: 0–5V

Triangular Wave (Vtri): 0 to 4.2V
Input Sine Wave (Vsin): -2 to 2V
Duty Cycle Calculation: ~96.4% at full power


Supply and Voltage Details
Supply Voltage Rail for Output Stage: ±35V (based on my calculations for Psupply and nominal Vcc).
Gate Voltage Requirement: ~10V (based on the MOSFET datasheets I’ve been looking at).

My Problem
I’ve worked with gate drivers before, like the IR2110 and UCC27200, but I’m struggling to integrate them into this design. I tried simulating them in TINA-TI, but the models don’t seem to work, and I might end up building the gate driver circuit from scratch.

Here’s where I need help:
Gate Driver Selection: How should I choose a gate driver that can handle a PWM signal at 300kHz and properly drive the MOSFETs at 10V?
MOSFET Selection: What key parameters should I look at for selecting MOSFETs that can handle ±35V rails and 50W output?
General Design Tips: Any reference books, papers, or online resources on gate driver design or Class D amplifier circuits would be a huge help.
Additional Context
I’ve read about things like dead time, shoot-through protection, and thermal considerations, but I’m still figuring out how to implement these properly. If anyone can provide insight or point me to resources, that would be amazing.

This is the "bare-bones" design that requires thermal dead-time compensation to be added and overcurrent protection.  https://www.handsontec.com/pdf_files/UM10155_2_Discrete_ClassD_Amp.pdf
